# Unable to paste text into virtual box guest

Tags: virtualbox, copy-paste, guest-additions

I am running virtualbox 4.2.4 r81684 on an ubuntu 12.10 installation with cinnamon desktop
I have just installed ubuntu 12.10 server in virtual box and I have guest additions installed
virtualbox was installed using these instructions http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/09/install-virtualbox-4-2-via-its-repository-in-ubuntu-12-04/

I have bi directional set under shared clipboard and there is a grey tick next to VBoxGuestAdditions.iso when I check the devices

So why is it that when I copy text from my host can I not paste it into my guest?
If I use CTRL+v on the command line of Ubuntu Server (guest) I get nothing and if I CTRL+v a second time I just get ASCII characters.

I get the same problem if I use Shift+Insert

Update

Session information shows that guest additions is not detected

```
￼
Runtime Attributes

Screen Resolution
640x480x32￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼

Clipboard Mode
Bidirectional￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼

Drag'n'Drop Mode
Bidirectional￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼

VT-x/AMD-V
Enabled￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼

Nested Paging
Enabled￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼

Guest Additions
Not Detected￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼

Guest OS Type
Ubuntu (64 bit)

Remote Desktop Server Port
Not Available￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼￼

￼
Storage Statistics

Controller: IDE Controller

  IDE Secondary Master:

    DMA Transfers
16￼

    PIO Transfers
534￼

    Data Read
49,152 B

    Data Written
0 B


Controller: SATA Controller

  SATA Port 0:

    DMA Transfers
6,606￼

    Data Read
159,972,352 B

    Data Written
3,717,120 B

￼
Network Statistics

Adapter 1

  Data Transmitted
2,170 B

  Data Received
16,977 B
```

Answer (score 2):

try shift + insert to paste into your guest terminal

Comment: Same problem, makes no difference!

Answer (score 2):

The <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>v</kbd> sequesnce is interpreted by the terminal as meaning *the next characters should be interpreted literally* so it's doing exactly that. You may be able to use

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>V</kbd>

to do what you want or right-click paste.